# Pyscript async requests need force wait for the data

Tags: python, asynchronous, pyscript

I am following the requests tutorial on pyscript here:
https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/requests.html
I am not familiar with asyncio and there is no fuller Pyscript impementation to guide my needs on waiting for a request to complete and return data.
Reading up on asyncio has not helped me so far.

I sucessfully get data from the server.
I need a way to force wait until the data is obtained from the server.

```
async def get_tp_data():
    # request() is a wrapper for pyfetch - see https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/tutorials/requests.html
    response = await request("https: the server site)", method="GET")
    #print(f"GET request=> status:{response.status}"), json:{await response.json()}")
    tp_response = await response.json()
    tp_expansion = tp_response['expansion']
    tp_extension = tp_expansion['extension']
    tp_contains = tp_expansion['contains']
    print(tp_expansion['contains'])  # Sucessfully gets the data
    return await tp_contains

tp_contains = asyncio.create_task(get_tp_data())

def run_comparison(*ags, **kws):
    # Code here is called by index.html button press, this works
    # Do stuff with tp_contains
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the syntax and the fact that you mention asyncio and use the response object, I'm guessing you're following [the other HTTP requests tutorial](https://docs.pyscript.net/latest/guides/http-requests.html#pyodide-http-pyfetch-and-fetchresponse) from the PyScript docs. The one you linked uses the [pyodide-http](https://github.com/koenvo/pyodide-http) package to patch the the requests package, and does not require asyncio. I think the tutorial you linked is actually the better route for small API requests that are unlikely to block for long, since it avoids the need for asyncio.

By utilizing `pyodide_http.patch_all()`, the [requests package](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) mostly just works. Here's a slimmed-down version of your code, using an API-testing endpoint:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<py-config>
    packages = ["requests", "pyodide-http"]
</py-config>

<py-script src="demo.py"></py-script>
<button py-click="run_comparison()">Get and Print Data</button>
```

```py
#demo.py
import pyodide_http
import requests

# Patch the Requests library so it works with Pyscript
pyodide_http.patch_all()

def get_tp_data():
    response = requests.get("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")
    return response.json()

def run_comparison(*ags, **kws):
    json_data = get_tp_data()

    #Do something interesting with the data
    print(f"The highest id is {max(item['id'] for item in json_data['data'])}")
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. Without your answer I would have had no idea of how to do this, as I did not think requests was able to be used in Pyscript at all. The only thing that occurs now is that in the Chrome console I get 'Refused to set unsafe header' messages for: User-Agent, Accept-encoding, Connection. This does not affect my current testing via 127.0.0.1:8000 - yet to test this further.

Comment: Happy to help! It's true, the unmodified version of the requests package doesn't work in PyScript or Pyodide - what the pyodide-http package does is rewrite some of the internals of that package to use Web API features that are available, like XMLHttpRequest, to maintain as consistent API while allowed some useful features. It's really quite clever.

Comment: I know you are busy developing PyScript. Maybe at some stage having a tutorial page or an example for this workflow would be good. P.s. any idea of when a beta, I intend to use this for a clients needs. (when public I can share it).